# Probability of selecting a red ball from the first box

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is from the 2017 Autumn FE Exam. I believe the answer should be 3/5 but according to the answer key, it's 3/20. Can you explain why?

*There are two boxes; the first box contains two green balls and three red balls; the second box contains three green balls and two red balls. A boy randomly selects a box from the two, and then randomly picks a ball from that box. If the ball is red, what is the probability that he selected the first box?*

I believe it's as simple as (3/5)/(3/5 + 2/5) = 3/5.

Comment: It is indeed $3/5$ due to Baye’s rule for computing $P[first | red]$. It is intuitively clear that the first box is more likely (given red). This is just a solution mistake where $3/10$ was divided by 2 instead of multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  It is an application of Bayes's Rule (along with the Law of Total Probability).  Labelling the events as $F$ for "is from the first box", and $R$ for "is a red ball". 
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(F\mid R)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(F)~\mathsf P(R\mid F)}{\mathsf P(F)~\mathsf P(R\mid F)+\mathsf P(F^\complement)~\mathsf P(R\mid F^\complement)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\tfrac 12{\cdot}\tfrac 35}{\tfrac 12{\cdot}\tfrac 35+\tfrac 12{\cdot}\tfrac 25}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{3}{5}\end{align}$$

---

**Alternatively:**   Since there is an equal count of balls in each box, each individual ball has the an equal probability for being selected, and *three* of the *five* red balls are in the first box.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of first box = $1/2.$

Probability of red ball in first box = $3/5.$

Probability of first box and red ball = $\dfrac 12 \cdot \dfrac 3{5}=\dfrac 3{10}.$